# Cannot open Android Studio on new laptop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows-11

I just got a laptop with Windows 11 preinstalled. I cannot open Android Studio. I've downloaded the JDK and Java of course, and other things such as setting the environment variables (JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, and STUDIO_JDK), uninstalling then reinstalling, and just about every solution posted on stackoverflow and Reddit. When I run studio.bat in command prompt, I receive this error:

```
Start Failed
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.<clinit>(IdeEventQueue.java:80)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.replaceSystemEventQueue(StartupUtil.java:784)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.patchSystem(StartupUtil.java:768)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:58)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$1$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:363)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected java.lang.Runnable java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.runnable accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt.event" to unnamed module u/76c3c2f
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil.findRunnableField(InvocationUtil.java:49)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil.<clinit>(InvocationUtil.java:17)
        ... 19 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.2+8-LTS-86 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2
```

Comment: Use the embedded JDK 11 instead.

Comment: @MartinZeitler How do I do that?

Comment: JDK comes embedded in Android Studio, so need to install JDK separately.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're trying to run Android Studio on Oracle `jdk-17.0.2` JRE, which will not work out. Unset or correct the environment variables, which cause it to fail. One only needs `JAVA_HOME` (JDK 11) and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` to build from CLI. It even runs on Oracle JDK, but you'd need this one: https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html

Once Android Studio is able to run, open a project, open "Module settings", then "Gradle settings"; there's usually a bunch of JDK to choose from; or set `org.gradle.java.home` per project. The path of that embedded JRE may vary - but Android Studio should use that path, unless providing something else - or something wrongful; for example: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\211.7628.21.2111.8139111\jre` ...

Comment: I actually just factory reset my computer, reinstalled the most recent JDK and then Android Studio and it worked. Not sure why, but I assume it has something to do with installing the most JDK after installing Android Studio.